# Yii2 and Editable (kartik or 2amigos) don't work

Tags: yii, yii2, x-editable

I'm working on a view.
I need to use the X-Editable plugin (kartik or 2amigos or the original) to edit some numbers.

I've installed with composer both Editable extension (kartik  / 2amigos)

```
                <th>Price</th>
            <td>
              <?= Editable::widget([
                    'model'=>$model, 
                    'inputType' => 'textInput',
                  'attribute' => 'price',
                  'asPopover' => true,
                  'header' => 'Name',
                  'size'=>'md',
                  'options' => ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Enter person name...']
              ]);?>
            </td>
```

But it didnt work: both Kartik or 2amigos.

Change the STYLE (2amigos the number became blu, Kartik the number is shown like a button) but it doesnt work. On click no error.

[image]

No Console error.

Someone could help me?
Thank you

**EDIT**
I've tryed https://jeditable.elabftw.net/ this one too but seems that jscript wont work on that page. We use AdminLTE. Some new idea?

Comment: are you trying to use editabe with popover ?

Comment: Both method (popover and inline) but no results

Comment: they do work i just copy pasted the code and it works correctly what version are you on , `Yii` and bootstrap ?

Comment: I've copy and pasted too... the Attribute take "css" from extension but nothing works. Yii2, Bootstrap 3+ ( I think there is a conflict)

Comment: can you share your `composer.json` or can you tell what is the `minimum-stability` set and is `prefer-stable` set to `true` ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/6MjANH0L

Comment: try changing `"minimum-stability" : "stable",` and `"prefer-stable" : true,` inside your `composer.json` or copy paste from here https://pastebin.com/UdDYsYKS, and then remove the extention editable from vendors directory and then run `composer update`

Comment: I'm trying let you know in few minutes

Comment: sure take your time .

Comment: Not so luky... Nothing is changed :(

Comment: did you removed the folder and updated composer ?

Comment: run `composer show -i` and check what version of the extension is installed for editable is it  `v1.7.6` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169963/discussion-between-gmazzacua-and-muhammad-omer-aslam).